# Printing out specific length in vector array

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to created a random password from the input text.
minimum length is 3. I found out that the first word which is The has size of 6 somehow.
Only the first word gives me weird size so far.
Eventually, I want to erase when words are  less than 3 words.
I don't know why it returns size 6.
Please advise.

```js
void setMinLength(std::vector<std::string> &words) {

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size()-1; i++) {
        if (words[i].size() == 6) {
            std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
            //words.erase(words.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::ifstream myFile("input.txt");
    if (!myFile.is_open()) { 
       std::cout << "Couldn't open the file."; 
       return 0;   
    }

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;

    while (myFile >> word) {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    setMinLength(words);
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Input.text file is below.

`The Project Gutenberg EBook of Grimms’ Fairy Tales, by The Brothers Grimm This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or`

```
The
Tales,
anyone
almost
re-use
online
Title:
Taylor
Marian
```

[hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZltM.jpg)

Comment: `if (!myFile.is_open()) { std::cout << "Couldn't open the file."; }` -- Your program then goes ahead and processes data, even though the file couldn't be opened.

Comment: If only the first word has an unusual size, perhaps your file has a Byte Order Mark. Open it in a hex editor and check. Note that a newline seems to have been printed before it.

Comment: `void setMinLength(std::vector<std::string> words)` -- Also, even though you commented out the `erase` line, that line wouldn't have had any effect on the vector in `main`, since you are passing the vector by value.

Comment: Also think about the effect of erasing from the vector while you are iterating over it.

Comment: I see something before the first The in the hex editor. what can I do ?

Comment: Should I do &words or *words for setMinLength ?

Comment: @parapara Can you post what you see in the Hex editor?

Comment: Pass by reference, `&`

Comment: I have uploaded. please check and thank you.

Comment: Your hex upload shows a Byte Order Mark. Simply delete those three bytes in your hex editor.

Comment: I have added & in the function parameter. thanks justANewbie!!

Comment: I added return 0 for my base case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your input text file, there is Byte Order Mark, so it affects the size of the word. Delete that.

In your `setMinLength(std::vector<std::string> &words)` function.

```cpp
void setMinLength(std::vector<std::string> &words) {

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size()-1; i++) {
        if (words[i].size() == 6) {
            std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
            //words.erase(words.begin() + i);
            // --i; explain below
        }
    }
}
```

Note if you use `erase()`: when you use `erase()`, `words[i]` is now the next word, then the loop increment `i` and you skip one word. Remember to `--i` at the end.

Comment: Hi, what if I cannot delete the word since this is a given text to work on ? should I talk to the person who gave me this if there is no way I can get correct size without deleting the first word ?

Comment: @parapara yes, you should.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I should have thought about --i  stuff.